# Creating a Terry Pratchett witch in Hero Quest

Tags: character-creation, heroquest-2

We are starting a Hero Quest RPG game.

I have decided I want to play a Terry Pratchett style witch, but am not sure how to do it.

I have decided to have my main skills (things) as charisma and mind control.  Would you consider that correct?  How would you do it?

Comment: This question needs a little more specificity.  In order to fit into the SE format, and for the answers to be good ones, a few more character building goals/objectives are needed to get focus the scope of the question.  If you are, at the moment, more interested in idea generation, you have enough reputation to drop by [RPG.SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=rpg.stackexchange.com) and kick some ideas around.  That may fit your needs better.